# Has anyone used a texture atlas with WebGL in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, textures, webgl, texture-mapping

I created a texture atlas and in Chrome there is some white on the edges of the cubes. However in Firefox it displays just fine. When I use colors there are not white edges either in Chrome or Firefox so it appears to be strictly a texturing problem. The texture atlas is 64 x 64 pixels and there are 16 total textures within the texture atlas at a width of 16 each.

Has anyone had a similar issue or know maybe why I am having this problem?

Comment: This sounds simple enough that maybe you could post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was caused by the fact that Chrome by default sets antialiasing on whereas Firefox does not.  This setting can be set when getting the WebGL context.  http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.2

Comment: I changed "Chrome by default sets aliasing" to "Chrome by default sets antialiasing".  Hope that's what you meant.  Did you figure out how antialiasing was causing the white edges?

Comment: That is what I meant and thanks for fixing that.  I don't know why that happened.  I'm pretty new to OpenGL.